# map route parameter to bool in asp.net web API

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have registered the following route right now:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "MediaHandler",
            routeTemplate: "api/mediahandler/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "PortalAsset", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And here is how the controller looks like:

```
 public class MediaHandlerController : ApiControllerBase
{
    ///...
      [HttpGet]
      [ActionName("download")]
      public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadAsset(long id)
      {
           // action
      }
```

I want to add boolean parameter to the controller - `isPreview` and want to map the routhe the following way:

1. http://host/api/mediahandler/download/1893 maps to: `id`=1893, `isPreview`=false
2. http://host/api/mediahandler/download/1893/preview maps to: `id`=1893, `isPreview` = true

Is there a way I can acomplish that?

Comment: You could do that with attribute routing. Any reason for choosing the default routing scheme over attribute routing?

Comment: @scheien the reason is that this is the single route scheme. By doing that by attributes I need to apply it to each action method or at least each controller. But for this case it might be what I need. Thanks for clue.

Comment: I see what you mean. You're welcome. Hope you'll sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

With [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) you can do like this

```
[RoutePrefix("api/mediahandler/download")]
public class MediaHandlerController : ApiControllerBase
{
      [HttpGet]
      [Route("{id}")]
      public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadAsset(long id)
      {
           return DownloadAsset(id, false);
      }

      [HttpGet]
      [Route("{id}/preview")]
      public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadAssetPreview(long id)
      {
          return DownloadAsset(id, true);
      }

      private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadAsset(long id, bool isPreview)
      {
           // action
      }
}
```

Comment: You could put 'api/mediahandler' as a `RoutePrefix` attribute on the class to shorten the routes on the actions themselves.